# Espresso: How to validate messages in logcat

Tags: android, android-espresso

Application fire different callbacks in different situation to device logs. I'm wondering if it's possible to validate what's in logcat using Espresso?

For example I need to make sure that after action A, in logs will be following line:
*11-26 04:35:45.037 30271-30310/com.test.testapp I/TestApp: **This is what I need to validate***

Answer (score 0):

If you mock the logger in the test you can then verify it being called with the desired parameters.